# how to tell custom checkout form with stripe api what form action is

Tags: stripe-payments

I am following the stripe guide here: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout

When I use the simple integration, my form works perfectly.  Here is the code for that:

```
<form action="/charges" method="post">
  <article>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: $5.00</span>
    </label>
  </article>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="MYDATAKEY"
          data-description="A month's subscription"
          data-amount="500"></script>
</form>
```

However, when I use the custom integration, my code does not go to the right action.  Instead, it goes to the page the form is on.  How can I fix the code below so that the form data goes to the right place.

```
<form action="/charges" method="post">
  <article>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: $5.00</span>
    </label>
  </article>
<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>
</form>
<script>
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'MYDATAKEY,
    image: '/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
    token: function(token) {
      // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
      // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
    }
  });

  $('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
      name: 'Demo Site',
      description: '2 widgets',
      amount: 2000
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Close Checkout on page navigation
  $(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  });
</script>
```

The problem might have to do with the token code, but I'm really not sure.  The problem i am trying to fix is that the form data go to the right place.

Comment: In custom checkout you get the token back via that token callback function, how you send the token to your server would be up to you. The two common ways are via an ajax call, or by appending it to a form as a hidden field and then submitting that form

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still very unclear on what to do.